# Copy a line from text file to shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, vim

Hello dear smart people,
If I'm in a login linux shell and I'm browsing a text file full of lines with vim or cat.

example

mar@001:~$ cat test

`sudo kill pluto
sudo echo $Parerino
sudo cut -d -f--d-f a -sdf-s-f 2> myerr
sudo kill pluto
sudo echo $PATH
sudo echo $Parerino`

How is possible to do the copy of the "sudo cut -d -f--d-f a -sdf-s-f 2> myerr" command, after I closed the file and paste it  in the shell so then I can execute it? or may I do it automatically?

How can I do that copy of that command that I need then open a new shell and paste the long command to modify it before to execute it?

Comment: Please contain your question marks.

Comment: Using the mouse is probably easiest... right-click, copy, close vi, paste.

Comment: we are talking in login shell, no GUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you most likely don't have a clipboard you won't be able to copy/paste from Vim to the shell.

But you can yank the current line and execute it with `:!`:

```
0y$
:!<C-r>"<CR>
```

Or you can execute the current line as returned by `getline`:

```
:!<C-r>=getline('.')<CR><CR>
```

Or you can write the line into a file and execute its content:

```
:.w foo
<C-z>
$ cat foo | sh
```

Or you can remember the line of your command, quit Vim and do:

```
sed -e 5p | sh
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your knowledge. thank you everybody.

Comment: grep PATH test | sh is my solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If no GUI at all, then I can only think of `gpm` and `screen`.  You may want to take a look at the following thread:  https://superuser.com/questions/67644/linux-copy-paste-in-tty